# Xcode 7: Custom keyboard is not showing in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, swift2, custom-keyboard

when i select **CKeyboard** than keyboard is showing in Simulator,

[image]

and when i Select **keyboard** at that time keyboard is not showing in simulator

[image]

i required to select **keyboard** but not showing Custom keyboard on simulator.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5):

Selected Simulator=>Hardware=>Keyboard=>Toggle Software keyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select Settings => General => Keybord => KeyBords => Select your Custom keybord(CKeybord).

then select 
Earth Symbol(near to 123)
[image: Earth Symbol(near to 123)]

You can able to open your custom keybord. Enjoy

Comment: Custom keyboard target is already shown but i want chose application target.